# How to find runway Centerline spacing on airport diagrams?

Tags: airport, airport-design, separation, parallel-runways

I know that airport diagrams show the exact position of airport runways in DMS (degrees, minutes, seconds) and therefore could use trigonometry to find how far apart runway centerlines are from adjacent parallels, but is there a more accurate way to find runway centerline spacing on these diagrams?

Comment: How accurate do you want to be? Do you know the accuracy of the published data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the airport diagram for Denver International Airport, which has numerous parallel runways.  I don't see any scale that could be used to measure distances.  Looks to me that one would have to do some math based on the latitude/longitude information provided, and which is provided here so no interpolation is needed:  https://www.airnav.com/airport/KDEN

[image]

Comment: You could take the known lengths of the runways to determine scale

Answer (score 2):

The scale is usually depicted on the chart. Just take a ruler and measure.

Comment: Good idea. I could measure any of the runways on CrossRoads's KDEN diagram to get 12000 ft. and then extrapolate to get the measurements I want!